# What is the best web based log viewer that is free / open source

Tags: .net, logging

On Windows and .Net 4.0   What is the best web based log viewer that is free / open source.

Comment: to see what kind of logs? IIS logs? log4net logs? NLog logs? NHibernate logs? SQL logs? Quartz.Net logs?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784131/are-there-any-c-open-source-log-viewers

Comment: A must would be flat file logs like Log4Net logs.  It would really cool to do also IIS logs..

Answer (score 1):

We had used [Elmah](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/), that do both, logging and web access to logs.
Elmah is designed to be used only for exception handling, and does not have functionality for integration with 3rd party loggers.

Answer (score 0):

log4net logs can be viewed with [Apache Chainsaw](http://logging.apache.org/chainsaw/index.html). It's not overly pretty and not web based, but very useful to search and filter a particular category in a massive log.